# How to clear or resetting UINavigation history?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, history

I have a game setup screen which uses UINavigation and am trying to reset or clear the UINavigation once a person has selected a color.

My app's current process can be best described in the following diagram:

```
Start application -> New game -> Pick character -> Pick Color -> Start game
```

Up until "Pick Color" I use the UINavigation, however when a color is picked I want to clear the UINavigation history.

The reason for doing this is so that you can't go back once you've started the game and want the UINavigation to with a clean slate with no indication that you can go back (and this also includes going back to the `main menu` screen).

The way I am doing it right now is thusly;

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

GameDashboardVC *dashboard = [[GameDashboardVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameDashboardVC" bundle:nil];
dashboard.title = @"Dashboard"; 
dashboard.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:dashboard animated:YES];

[dashboard release];
```

The problem is that it pops to the rootViewController but it never pushes the dashboard onto the stack.

I've tried:

```
[self.parentViewController.navigationController pushViewController....]
```

The only thing I haven't tried is putting my dashboard push inside the root view controller itself, but I am concerned because I am not sure if it should even be there.

Therefore, where is the correct place to put this kind of functionality, and how do I clear the UINavigation's stack.

Thank you for your time/help.

Comment: Go through your UINavigationController viewControllers property and throw away the ones you don't want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem now to my satisfaction.

I put the following code inside my initWithNibName method:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

This hid the back button and I didn't have to pop anything, but I think for memory reasons it might be useful to keep the idea of removing un-necessary items from the stack.

But for now the above will do.

Comment: I did another solution where I put all the "new game init" stuff inside a modal view with its own uinavigation.  The modal view way works just as well and could be argued as being more logical.  The only issue is when you remove the modal and push the main menu view onto the stack.  Having said that, either way seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want reset the UINavigation History, reinitialise the navigation controller.

if you using UINavigationController from AppDelegate class. You can reinitialise the navigation history.

appDelegate.navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]init];

Above code will reset the navigationController history..